# Image not getting displayed in outlook

Tags: c#, sql-server, outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 and C# lang and SQL Server. Basically I am saving an image in the database with `<img>` tag and the SQL Server job sends out the image in an email. I am able to view the image on gmail but not in Outlook. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: In Outlook is there an Information icon in the information bar of the message containing the image? If so click that and you should get some options for displaying images.

Comment: Where is the info bar? I see image as an 'X'

Comment: It's the bit at the top of the message which tells you when it was sent, who from, who to etc. The icon is a small blue circle with a white 'i' in it.

Comment: The message has no info bar / icon. Basically i want to save an image in DB so that it gets shown on other recipients outlook.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could remove the information bar from an Outlook email message.